# In Eclipse, how to disable red underline in only one case?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, underline

If you use PyDev plugin for Eclipse, and if you import arcpy, you get red underline when you try to call arcpy.da.SearchCursor or arcpy.da.InsertCursor, etc. Eclipse thinks that is "Undefined variable from import". But they're exist and I can use them without any trouble. This red underline is a bit annoying. 
I would be happy if I would be able to disable the red underline only in these cases.

Can I do that somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You can disable the error "Undefined Variable from import".**

Go to  Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined

For "Undefined Variable from import" select "ignore".

**2. You can disable the red underlining for errors in general.**

This is not exactly what you asked for, but an internet search for "eclipse disable red underline" brings up this question, so here is a link to the answer:

[Eclipse CDT: Disable red underlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423184/eclipse-cdt-disable-red-underlining/28364750#28364750)